# C++ Variable Scope error

Tags: c++, scope

The Error i got it: "list was not defined in this scope" [ inside main() ]
    I've tried a couple of things but ended a failure. I've read through some scope tutorials and didn't find anything :\, so i came here, hope someone can help.

[CODE:]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


const int MAX_LIST_SIZE = 100;
typedef int element;
typedef element list_type[MAX_LIST_SIZE];


void bubble_sort();

int main() {
    cout << list[0] << list[1] << list[2] << list[3] << list[4] << endl;
    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort(list_type list, int n) {

    list[0] = 43;
    list[1] = 20;
    list[2] = 24;
    list[3] = 31;
    list[4] = 36;

    n = 5;
    int j, k;
    bool exchange_made = true;
    element temp;

    k = 0;
    // make up to n- 1 passes through array, exit
    // early if no exchange are made on previous pass
    while((k < n -1 ) && exchange_made) {
        exchange_made = false;
        ++k;
        // number of comparisons on kth pass
        for (j = 0; j < n - k; ++j)
        if(list[j] > list[j + 1]) {
            // exchange must be made!
            temp = list[j];
            list[j] = list[j + 1];
            list[j + 1] = temp;
            exchange_made = true;
        }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {

    cout << list[0] << list[1] << list[2] << list[3] << list[4] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Well `list` is only defined in the function `bubble_sort`, so there is know way that `main` can have access to it. That is one problem. Here is something to get you started.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


const int MAX_LIST_SIZE = 100;
typedef int element;
typedef element list_type[MAX_LIST_SIZE];


void bubble_sort();

int main() {
    bubble_sort(); //you need to actually CALL bubble_sort for it to do anything
    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort() {
    list_type list; //no need to have the variables as a parameter
    int n = 5;      //just declare them in the scope (inside the function) that you need them in
    list[0] = 43;
    list[1] = 20;
    list[2] = 24;
    list[3] = 31;
    list[4] = 36;

    int j, k;
    bool exchange_made = true;
    element temp;

    k = 0;
    // make up to n- 1 passes through array, exit
    // early if no exchange are made on previous pass
    while((k < n -1 ) && exchange_made) {
        exchange_made = false;
        ++k;
        // number of comparisons on kth pass
        for (j = 0; j < n - k; ++j)
        if(list[j] > list[j + 1]) {
            // exchange must be made!
            temp = list[j];
            list[j] = list[j + 1];
            list[j + 1] = temp;
            exchange_made = true;
        }
   }

    cout << list[0] << list[1] << list[2] << list[3] << list[4] << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you never declared `list` your main block. The the error message is clearly telling you the problem.

Comment: functions have their own local scope. So main has no idea about `list` from within the `bubble_sort` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should have defined `list`. It is not defined anywhere.

```
int arr[MAX_LIST_SIZE];
```